# Stripe country ranges request in stripe-react-elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I see a request to 
`https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/data/countryRanges-4321some11hash1234.json` in stripe-react-elements.

I can't find the data anywhere but the `<CardElement />` component waits for the call to load before it displays anything.

To make the user experience better I'd like to show a loading spinner instead, while I wait for it to load; so I need to track the data down.

Could someone point me towards where the data is?

My components look like

```
const PaymentDetails = () => {
  const stripe = window.Stripe("pk_test_123abc");
  return (
    <StripeProvider stripe={stripe}>
      <Elements>
        <InjectedCardDetail stripe={stripe} />
      </Elements>
    </StripeProvider>
  );
};

const CardDetail = ({ stripe }) => {
  const [{ token }, setState] = React.useState({ token: null });
  const submit = () => {
    stripe.createToken({ name: "Name" }).then(({ token }) => {
      setState({ token });
    });
  };
  return (
    !token && (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="cardnumber">
          <div>
            <p>Please provide your card details.</p>

            {/* This is where I'd like to optionally render
            countryRanges ? <MyLoadingSpinner /> : ...
            assuming that's the thing to do here */}

            <CardElement style={{ base: { fontSize: "20px" } }} />
          </div>
        </label>
        <button onClick={submit}>Save Card</button>
      </div>
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: You might want to look into using the `element.on('ready')` function: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#element-on You could initially show your spinner and then hide it when the 'ready' callback is made.

Comment: That did it, you're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulAsjes I managed to cobble together a nice solution.

The final version looks like this: for anyone who's curious.

```
const CardDetail = ({ stripe }) => {
  /* new state, ready */
  const [{ ready, token }, setState] = React.useState({
    ready: false,
  });

  const submit = () => {
    stripe.createToken({ name: "Name" }).then(({ token }) => {
      setState({ token });
    });
  };
  /* I added this */
  const onReady = () => setState({ error, ready: true });

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <p>Please provide your card details.</p>
        {/* this shows/hides my spinner */}
        {!ready && <MyLoadingSpinner size="small" />}
        {/* and listen here ↓ */}
        <CardElement onReady={onReady} style={{ base: { fontSize: "20px" } }} />
      </label>
      <button onClick={submit}>
        Save Card
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```